# Android:In listview when checked on particular checkboxes multiple checkboxes get checked

Tags: android

In listview multiple items get checked on checking a single checkbox when iterating through the listview any gueses i have created only single checkbox with unique  id and iterated it through listview

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because of **view recycling** .. you should use view holder and check for position before setting the checkbox..

check http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/